# How can we deploy package.xml file through apex code into the org?

Tags: apex, deployment, package.xml

I have one question,i created one **package.xml** file and how can i deploy to org without using any tool like(eclipse,ant,migration,change set), is there any way to deploy through apex code or any back end process.if you know anything can you provide that information.

Comment: use metatdata in apex for deployment process.

Comment: Why do you want to deploy package.xml file? if you simply deploy your components the package.xml will be automatically updated with that.

Comment: You don't store the package.xml in your org...it is meaningless without some form of IDE or deployment tool. This question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The question needs to be clarified, but is valid for certain edge cases. For example, we are dynamically creating package.xml files for migration purpose. We would like to then deploy it through code. Yes, we can store the xml file and then use IDE/Workbench to deploy it, but that adds additional manual step.

Answer (score 1):

https://workbench.developerforce.com can deploy Package XMLs without any need to install software - however use with caution!

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench#Utilities